# System Error In IIS 7.5 server hosted website

Tags: iis-7.5, viewstate, system-error

We hosted one of our web application in IIS 7.5 based web server. "Its giving System error".

Environment Structure is :
1. 2 IIS 7.5 servers configured for load balancing.
2. AKAMAI configured for caching
3. Each server has one individual private IP.
4. 1 Public IP configured to access load balancer. 
5. .Net framework 4.0
6. Managed pipeline - Integrated.
7. Identity - application Pool Identity
8. bindings - test.com/www.test.com/origin-www.test.com

Results of the web application is

1. web application working good in individual server.
2. working good in cluster IP .
3. "origin-www" domain also working good.

but it doesn't work in the binding, test.com and www.test.com

It shows the error as "System Error".

When I check the event viewer I see the message that "view state integrity checks failed"

(But in both servers machine key is same.)

Comment: Double and triple check the machine key: is it set for all IIS or for the individual Web site? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx for details.